# In what year was package-private visibility semantics introduced to the java language?

Tags: java, package-private

What is the best way I can answer similar questions?

(What year feature XXX was introduced to java?)

I have read the wiki on java version history but it is too coarse grained.

Thanks!

Comment: Click on the checkbox to the left of the answer and it will turn green.  That answer will be marked as "accepted".  It gives that person five reputation and moves their answer to the top if it's not already there.  It's a nice way of saying "thanks, you helped me."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package-private has been around since before it was Java. The original Oak had public, protected, and default (package private) visibility. Eventually private (the modern "compilation unit" private) was introduced, still before Java 1.0.

**Edit**: I just checked up on this: Oak *called* it `private`, but it behaved like Java's package-private: "All classes in a particular package can use all variables and methods declared in the classes in that package, regardless of public, protected, and private declarations." (Oak 0.2 spec page 15) Anyway, the date on that would be at least 1994 (version 0.2 of the spec), probably earlier.

[Here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue055.html) is an interesting article on Java history.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. great overview indeed.
But in that light, why did Martin Fowler claim in 2002, that modern languages lack language support for a distinction between public and published interfaces (http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf). Seems to me that package private (or internal in .Net) is meant precisely for this purpose.

Comment: @Vitaliy: What Fowler is getting at is that a "published" interface - one that is part of an external library - is much harder to modify than a public method within code that you control.

Answer (score 2):

All the past versions are available and have dates on them:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/